# Does the crime fighting in Lucifer go more or less "by the book"?

Tags: lucifer

I've been looking for a new crime procedural to watch on Netflix, but because I live in Belgium, the selection is quite limited. I've recently been told about Lucifer, and it appears somewhat interesting.

There is one problem though: I hate it when the crime fighters aren't following the rules, laws and regulations in crime procedurals, because I'm a firm believer that those rules are there for a reason and are important in protecting the rights of innocents and ensuring that people who are sentenced for crimes deserve to do so. For example, I had to give up on Luther after 2 episodes because Luther couldn't work by the book.

now, from what I understand, Lucifer is a devil. I'm not sure what he's doing on Earth or why he was sent there (trying to avoid spoilers here), but I'm worried that because he's a devil, he might have a preference for disobeying these important rules. Is my worry justified and is Lucifer wont to break the rules? Or does he actually try to somewhat follow generally established rules around crime fighting?

Comment: The guy is literall Satan. It's very far away from procedural crime. It's something like Mentalist with the change he get the confession by showing his "true" face. Or something like that.

Comment: I can't recall specific scenes, but yes. There are many times where Lucifer breaks protocol. Most notably they let him interrogate suspects even though he's only a "consultant", he sometimes sneaks around crime scenes to look for clues himself, and he uses magic to get people confess things they normally wouldn't. He also punishes deals punishment to suspects after a confession (although they abandon that for the most part in later seasons).

Comment: @DeeV It's interesting you give these examples, because consultants "sneaking around crime scenes" and "interrogating suspects" is something that also happens in Elementary, and I actually like that show there. It's mostly the "we're tampering with evidence" or the "we've put this suspect in mortal danger so he'd confess" or the "we're going after suspects on our own with no backup and no evidence" things that happen in Luther or some other shows that bother me, because those are generally things that are done to entrap innocents IRL.

Comment: @Nzall  In that case, maybe he's actually a better crime fighter than others shows. I can't think of any situations where he entraps people other than his use of magic. There are few instances where they have a suspect and he uses his power to make them confess though more often than not his power actually reveals the suspect is innocent. He is the literal devil though so he has a strong sense of justice and believes people should get what they deserve. He'll punish people outside the criminal justice system without due process (though it's always after a confession).

Comment: @DeeV Interesting. Do you think you could pour your comments into an answer so I have something to accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many instances in Lucifer where he breaks protocol. He is the literal devil and as such he doesn't really feel the need to follow rules whether they be human's or God's.

His most notable transgressions is to [punish people](https://youtu.be/17PFPkPUtXw?t=125) who he feels deserves it. He is the Devil after all. It's his job. He sometimes uses [excessive force](https://youtu.be/s7tmGq9ZWRg?t=40) against the suspects. In the human world this would be considered illegal because it is outside the law without any trial or due-process, but the context of the show the police let it slide (or they don't know). It's *always* against the suspect of the episode *after* there has been a confession. He never harms or hurts anybody innocent.

Another, not necessarily illegal but against protocol, is his ability to get people to [confess their darkest desires](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=azWXAuSaLM0). He often uses this ability to gather clues as to what motivations someone may have to kill someone. The police view it as a form of hypnotism so they will often ask him to interrogate suspects or witnesses to see what he can draw out. This is unorthodox as Lucifer is never hired as a law enforcer and is always a consultant for the police department.

There have also been scenarios where he will break in to a crime scene alone to have a look himself. I can recall a few instances where he has carelessly tampered with a crime scene, but it's never to entrap a suspect. He is just very curious about humans and sometimes gets carried away. He mostly lets the police do their job and just observes while making cheeky commentary.

Without getting too deeply in spoilers, there is one instance I can recall where the police do something illegal to entrap a suspect. However, the show acknowledges that what they are doing is wrong, and it's actually part of the story. The culprits involved get punished unlike most cop shows where breaking the law is commonplace.